# How to set cookies in Cypress before visiting react app running on localhost

Tags: testing, cookies, cypress, jsessionid

The steps I want to take are:

2. Start the Cypress test-suite and use `cy.setCookie` to set the JSESSIONID cookie (already acquired and up-to-date)
3. **After** the cookie is set, then use `cy.visit` to access the running app

The issue:

- The cookie is not set before `cy.visit` runs and this causes the app redirect to an unauthorized page

What I have done so far:

```
Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
  preserve: 'JSESSIONID'
})

cy.setCookie('JSESSIONID', Cypress.env('JSESSIONID'), {
  path: '/',
  domain: '<domain.name>',
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true,
  sameSite: 'no_restriction',
  log: true,
}).then(() => cy.visit('localhost:3000/<authenticated-route>')
```

It might be worth mentioning that <domain.name> is of the form [www.staging.etc.com](http://www.staging.etc.com) whereas  is running locally: localhost:3000/

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

To set the cookie in the `onBeforeLoad` hook and avoid the error from `cy.setCookie()`, you can use `Cypress.browser`

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/#dashboard', {
  onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow) => {
    Cypress.browser.cookies.set({
      path: '/',
      domain: '<domain.name>',
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'no_restriction',
      log: true,
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Provide an onBeforeLoad callback function](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit.html#Provide-an-onBeforeLoad-callback-function)

The example recipe mentioned (code is [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/194a85456fc04900b182e225c3bfd9979693550f/examples/logging-in__jwt/cypress/integration/spec.js#L24)) is setting a token in local storage, but should apply as well to cookies

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/#dashboard', {
  onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow) => {
    cy.setCookie('JSESSIONID', Cypress.env('JSESSIONID'), {
      path: '/',
      ...
    })
  }
})
```

I think the problem is that `cy.visit()` is one of the places where everything is cleared down, but the hook is provided to get around that. Although, I would expect `preserve` to work as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately Cypress gives an error when cy.setCookie is used within cy.visit: `Cypress detected that you returned a promise from a command while also invoking one or more cy commands in that promise.`. I think Cypress expects non-asynchronous operations inside the onBeforeLoad hook using the provided contentWindow object. I'm going to keep looking, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by doing a cy.request to login before using cy.visit.

Code looks something like this:

```js
const login = () => {
  const headers = new Headers()
  headers.append("Content", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  headers.append("Accept-Encoding", "gzip:deflate")
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

  cy.request({
    url: Cypress.env("LOGIN_URL"),
    method: 'POST',
    form: true,
    headers,
    body: {
      "email": Cypress.env("EMAIL"),
      "password": Cypress.env("PASSWORD")
    }
  }).then((response) => {
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response.body)
    setCookie(response.COOKIE)
  })
}

export const loginAndStartTests = () => {
  login()
  cy.visit('/<homepage>')
}
```

Comment: That's just the standard recipe given by Cypress. The question gives the impression you wanted to avoid obtaining a new token for each login.

Comment: what is response.COOKIE? Where are you getting that from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a cookie from the argument `contentWindow`:

A cookie setter util:

```js
export const setCookieToContentWindow = (
  contentWindow,
  name,
  value,
  { expireMinutes = 1 } = {},
) => {
  const date = new Date();
  const expireTime = expireMinutes * 60 * 1000;

  date.setTime(date.getTime() + expireTime);

  const assignment = `${name}=${encodeURIComponent(value)}`;
  const expires = `expires=${date.toGMTString()}`;
  const path = 'path=/';

  contentWindow.document.cookie = [assignment, expires, path].join(';');
};
```

Using `onBeforeLoad`:

```js
cy.visit('http://localhost:3000/#dashboard', {
  onBeforeLoad: (contentWindow) => {
    setCookieToContentWindow(contentWindow, 'COOKIE_NAME', 'COOKIE_VALUE');
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do, is set the cookie with the [`Cookie` HTTP header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie):

```js
cy.visit('/whatever', {
  headers: {
    'Cookie': '<cookie-name>=<cookie-value>'
}})
```